# How to set MySql grant to allow external connection to MySql?

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

I am not so into DB and I have the following problem.

I have installed a **MySql 5.7.17** on a remote **Ubuntu 16.04** server and I have to connect to this server from a client installed on my laptop.

So The first thing that I have done is that I have changed the **bind-address** directive values (into the **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf** file) from:

```
Bind-address=127.0.0.1
```

to:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

to allow also external connection.

The problem is that when I try to connect from my client (installed on my laptop) I obtain this error:

```
Host 'XXX.YYY.ZZ.JJ' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

(where **XXX.YYY.ZZ.JJ* is my laptop IP address).

From what I have understood I also have to give to the mysql user w the db permissions to connect from any host and not just from localhost.

I think that it should be something related to the grant: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html

What exactly have I to do? I think that I have to access to MySql from my server shell (via SSH) and then perform a query that grant some privileges to the **root** user (the MySql user) to allow to access from outside.

But I don't know what exactly I have to do. How can I allow this external connection for the roo user?

Comment: Have you attempted to create an administrator user instead of using root?

Comment: @kgrwhite no, what is the difference?

Comment: It's possibly a precaution that stops root access from external sources. This would find out if it's the case.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, you need to login to mysql server with root access and then run following command on mysql prompt

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_db_name.* TO 'your_db_user_name'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
```

you can also specify a specific IP instead of %

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_db_name.* TO 'your_db_user_name'@'your_IP_here' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
```

you can also specify a for all databases

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'your_db_user_name'@'your_IP_here' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
```

Comment: and can I specify to ALL databases on my MySql?

Comment: Yes, my answer is updated with another command for all databases